# Use of undeclared identifier 'imagePickerController'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm receiving the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'imagePickerController'` in my image picker `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate on the following line:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

I've added the protocol's to the interface as well:

```
@interface MyMediaController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Also, I added the MobileCoreServices.framework binary to be linked with the binary and imported it as so:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

This is how I'm instantiating the imagePicker:

```
- (IBAction)takePhotoButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        self.isNewMedia = YES;
    }
}
```

---

Any ideas on why I'm receiving this error? It's odd because this was working previously, and just seemed to stop working for no particular reason.

Edit:
Here's the code preceding the error line:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 15, 150);
}

- (MyMediaCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyMediaCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyMediaCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyMediaCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    AccountModel *account = [AccountModel getInstance];
    NSString *fileName = [[self.mediaResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"filename"];
    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/developd/premium_media/%@/thumb.%@", account._id, fileName];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPath]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Show some context by showing more code before the problem line.

Comment: I used Select All - "Control I" and it automatically re-indented for me, and I was able to see that the lines for NSURLConnection were malformed. You were both right, would it be useful to set that as the answer? re-indenting the code made it obvious where the issue was.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be wary about using the `cell` reference inside the asynchronous block. If you're on a slow network, you run the risk that the cell may have been reused for a different `NSIndexPath` before the image was successfully retrieved. You should re-retrieve the appropriate cell reference before trying to update the image or else you risk having update the image for the wrong `NSIndexPath`. Also, needless to say, you might consider using `NSURLSession` given that `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I actually was getting incompatible block pointer type errors because of that, I put everything but setting the cell imageView property outside of the async block and it's working great and no errors! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these sorts of cryptic errors if you've have mismatched braces or parentheses in the method preceding `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. You can identify missing braces if you select all of your code and then press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> (or chose "Editor" - "Structure" - "Re-Indent") and as it re-indents your code, the missing brace will jump out at you.

In this case, it's because the `completionHandler` block of the `sendAsynchronousRequest` method is not terminated in the preceding method, `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.